# Compare Double.MIN_VALUE and 0

Tags: java, if-statement, double

Why this code does't work? Actually,this is just the small part of a big program. It has to compare `Double.MIN_VALUE` to different values, it works with all values except `0.` ,why? Thanks!

```
double d = Double.MIN_VALUE;
if (0. > d) {
    System.out.println("OK");
}
```

Comment: `Double.MIN_VALUE` is greater than `0`. For example `0x0.0000000000001P-1022; // 4.9e-324`

Answer (score 4):

The `Double.MIN_VALUE` is `4.9E-324`. And this is not less than `0`. But it is not actually `0`.

If you print

```
System.out.println(4.9E-324d > 0.);//this is true
```

In this sense,

> 0.0000000000...0001 != 0. But it tends to 0

The same way `4.9E-324d != 0 but tends to 0`

Answer (score 2):

You are doing decimal number comparison. If you say try something like:

```
 System.out.println(0.000000000000001d == 0.);//print false
```

You will get false. If i read java docs it says:

```
/**
 * A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type
 * {@code double}, 2<sup>-1074</sup>. It is equal to the
 * hexadecimal floating-point literal
 * {@code 0x0.0000000000001P-1022} and also equal to
 * {@code Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L)}.
 */
```

So its near to zero but not really 0.

Answer (score 2):

`Double.MIN_VALUE` is actually a bad name for the constant in Java. It does not fit to [`int.MIN_VALUE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MIN_VALUE). In C# it is called [Double.Epsilon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which IMHO fits better.

So, `Double.MIN_VALUE` is not the largest negative double value that exists. IMHO such a constant doesn't even exist in JAVA by default.

Answer (score 0):

`Double.MIN_VALUE` is equal to the hexadecimal floating-point literal `0x0.0000000000001P-1022` and also equal to `Double.longBitsToDouble(0x1L).`

So your condition fails!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to compare a value to the smallest number (the negative value with the greatest magnitude) you might want to look at [`Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY) which the Java documentation states is:

"A constant holding the negative infinity of type double. It is equal to the value returned by Double.longBitsToDouble(0xfff0000000000000L)."